watching impermanent sensation with equanimity
I am going for minor operation. Should I ask for anesthesia or do without it(seeing the unpleasant sensation equanimously) ?
And when I have orgasm or very tasty food it's very difficult to see the sensation equanimously. What to do?
Any tips to remain in equanimity in orgasm ?(too difficult!)

Do you have anything against anesthesia or are you just using this as an opportunity to meditate on equanimity w.r.t physical sensations?

@Desmon opportunity to meditate

The Buddha taught the middle way between indulgence in sensual pleasures, and extreme asceticism.
To me, undergoing surgery without anesthesia would fall under extreme ascetism.
Even monks were allowed by the Vinaya to take medicine and undergo treatment.
So, being anesthetized for surgery or taking painkillers for pain, would fall under the middle way, in my opinion.

It seems that you take pleasure in orgasm and delicious food. With equanimity you rise above both pain and pleasure. You give up both or you end up giving up neither. Because you do not have perfect grasp of equanimity it will be better for you to take anesthesia. However those who have perfected equanimity need not worry about any pain.
You want to develop equanimity. For that you need to understand impermanence of body , feelings , perceptions, choices and consciousness. There is no pleasure in pleasure and no pain in pain because they are impermanent. Pleasurable feeling becomes painful in due time and painful feelings become pleasurable in due time. You need to give up both. You should not find pleasure in pleasurable things and no pain in painful things. That’s equanimity.

It would be very hard to convince a surgeon that one would like to do an operation without anaesthetics so as to meditate on equanimity. As any surgeon agreeing to forgo anaesthetics in their operations are opening themselves to being sue for malpractices especially if there is resulting complications. One would need a very solid reason such as being allergic to anaesthetics or having an underlying heart condition (in the case of general anaesthesia) to opt out of anaesthesia. In the case of minor operation, it will likely involve local anaesthesia; making it harder to justify doing without.
Ven. Thanissaro said in his talks that our mind is like a committee. There are many different voices with different agenda in the committee. Even if there is a unanimous decision to forego anaesthetics at the beginning of the operation, there is no guarantee that there won’t be any dissenting voices during the operation. What if during the surgery, a part of the mind got sick and tired of bearing the incessant pain? What is plan B? Or are we going to simply use our concentration to fight and endure the pain as a student of Ajahn Fuang (Ven. Thanissaro’s teacher) did. (Note: she had allergic reaction to the anaesthesia so there wasn’t any options).

After the treatment Ajaan Fuang visited her at the hospital. She told him that she had been able to concentrate her mind so as to endure the pain, but it had left her exhausted.

Perhaps the approach you are trying to achieve is similar to Ajahn Fuang’s advice to the student, “to see that it's not you. It's not yours. Your awareness is one thing, the pain is something separate.”. However, I still think we should not begin our sword practise only in a battlefield. Yes, it will motivate us to master the sword quickly but it is just too hair-raising.
Personally, I would prefer to have a backup plan. An alternative is using concentration to block out all physical sensations such as the one related by Ven. Thanissaro on his teacher Ajahn Fuang.

He then told me of the time he had undergone kidney surgery and, not trusting the anesthesiologist, had put himself in that state for the duration of the operation.

The mental state mentioned was asanna-bhava (state of non-perception). I believe any of the jhana states offer an escape from physical sensations. Again, this is on the premise that one had sufficient mastery to enter such meditative state at will.
I think the idea that equanimity is to be able to put up with sensations (mental or physical) in a stoic manner may not be right. Equanimity arises from causes. It begins with seeing how the mind jumps like a monkey even in the midst of sensual pleasures. On eating wisely, Ajahn Brahm once said:

Even when we do eat in silence, we often fail to savour the moment. Instead, while we are chewing on one piece of food, our attention is distracted as we look at our plate to choose the next thing on our fork. Some are even two or three forkfuls ahead of themselves—one forkful is in the mouth, one is waiting on the fork, another is heaped up waiting on the plate, while the mind contemplates the morsel coming third on the fork.

Be it very tasty food or orgasm, it is seeing the reason behind why our mind flicker and run around, never staying still even in the midst of sensual pleasures that give rise to equanimity. The reason is that we have absolutely no control over the pleasures and joys that arose from our senses. The mind cannot command the pleasures to remain forever. And when they begin to fade, there is nothing that can be done to prevent it. Similarly, the mind cannot recreate these pleasures out of nothing, will them into existence just by snapping the fingers. Even fantasizing requires imaginations and engaging mental images. So, this in essence is the only thing that the mind can do; to initiate another round of craving and try to recreate the causes that give rise to pleasures. It is seeing this clearly and deeply that give rise to disenchantment and dispassion and leading eventually to equanimity.
It is not like there is nothing but disappointment in the midst of disenchantment and dispassion. It is precisely because the mind discovers that there is a peace within that is not touch by the world. And this inner peace and well-being can be enhanced and developed through insights and discernment with its side effect being equanimity.

Tasty food or bodily pain generate sensations or vedana. These sensations can be watched with equanimity, which means watching the sensations without craving.
Orgasm is the result of craving therefore orgasm cannot be watched with equanimity.
Since you are still craving for orgasms, it is probably best you ask for anesthesia.

isn't orgasm a pleasant sensation (धारा प्रवाह )

Orgasm includes pleasant sensations however orgasm is lust. Lust is not equanimity. Getting angry also includes unpleasant sensations but anger is obviously not equanimity.
